# Using MongoTemplate to insert a JSONObject, how do I prevent the "map" object from being added to my Document?

Tags: spring, mongodb, insert, mapping, mongotemplate

Using MongoTemplate to insert a JSONObject my code is:

```
mongoTemplate.insert(jsonObject, collection);
```

My JSONObject.toString() looks like:

```
{"Event":{"Object":"Value","Object":"Value"}}
```

When it's mapped into  MongoDB, it looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("542ed489881654a415ca836d"),
"_class" : "org.json.JSONObject",
"map" : {
    "Event" : {
        "map" : {
            "Object":"Value", 
            "Object":"Value"
```

How do I remove "map" from being added when inserted to my DB?

Answer (score 0):

Use pojo class, and you will not have such problems

```
public class User {
    private String password;
    // getter and setter;
}

User user = new User();
mongoTemplate.insert(user);
```

or try insert

```
Map<String, Object>
```